# Why can I not run commands on a node?

Tags: iri-node, iri-legacy-api

I am trying to query a node:

```
curl http://my.node.addr:14265 \
>   -X  POST \
>   -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
>   -H 'X-IOTA-API-Version:  1' \
>   -d '{"command": "getNodeInfo"}'
```

But it returns:

```
{"error":"COMMAND getNodeInfo is not available on this node","duration":0}
```

The API port is obviously bound; why can I not run any commands against it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This occurs when you launch the full node with the `--remote-limit-api` flag and disallow the use of certain commands. Normally it is used to disallow access to attachToTangle, but the same could happen with getNodeInfo too.